# Merge multiple dataframes in R

Tags: r

I need to merge multiple dataframe with the matching values in column `A`. What is the most efficient way to do this and get the `result`.

df1

```
A  B  C
2  x  r
1  c  r
3  y  t
```

df2

```
A  D  E
3  e  y
1  t  t 
2  y  t
```

df3

```
A  F  G
1  g  y
2  f  y
3  h  k
```

result

```
A  B  C  D  E  F  G  
1  c  r  t  t  g  y
2  x  r  y  t  f  y
3  y  t  y  t  h  k
```

Comment: Is that really just a `cbind` or are you looking for a join of common values where not all values of `A` exist in all data frames?

Comment: @Gopala No I do not want to do cbind. I am not sure if all the dfs have same number of rows.

Comment: Interesting. Yeah, it is a very good solution if you truly have a variable length list of data frames. Thank you for posting.

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to use `dplyr` package and it's `inner_join` as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- inner_join(df1, df2)
df <- inner_join(df, df3)
```

Resulting output is:

```
df
  A B C D E F G
1 2 x r y t f y
2 1 c r t t g y
3 3 y t e y h k
```

Note, `inner_join` keeps only rows where `A` matches.

If you want it arranged by column `A`, you can add this line:

```
arrange(df, A)
  A B C D E F G
1 1 c r t t g y
2 2 x r y t f y
3 3 y t e y h k
```

To merge a variable length list of data frames, it appears Reduce can be helpful along with the above `inner_join`:

```
df <- Reduce(inner_join, list(df1, df2, df3))
arrange(df, A)
  A B C D E F G
1 1 c r t t g y
2 2 x r y t f y
3 3 y t e y h k
```

Comment: Thanks , but merging the list of dataframe would be much better.

Comment: You can use base package's `merge` by nesting the merges as I am basically nesting the merges using `inner_join`. It will be slower. Unaware of any other solution, but will see if others post something different.

Comment: Added the `Reduce` option with `inner_join`. Not sure if that fits what you want.