# Combine several data.frames into one (keep every rownames)

Tags: r

I have input dataframes `Berry` and `Orange`

```
Berry = structure(list(Name = c("ACT", "ACTION", "ACTIVISM", "ACTS", 
"ADDICTION", "ADVANCE"), freq = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("Name", 
"freq"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Orange = structure(list(Name = c("ACHIEVE", "ACROSS", "ACT", "ACTION", 
"ADVANCE", "ADVANCING"), freq = c(1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("Name", 
"freq"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Running the following operation will give me the desired `output`

```
output = t(merge(Berry,Orange, by = "Name", all = TRUE))
rownames(output) = c("","Berry","Orange")
colnames(output) = output[1,]
output = output[2:3,]
output = data.frame(output)
```

However, now I have to create `output` from *72* dataframes similar to `Berry` and `Orange`. Since `merge` appears to work with only two `data.frame` at a time, I'm not sure what would be the best approach for me. I tried `rbind.fill` which kept the values but lost the `Names`. I found [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8091303/7128934) and [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36732127/7128934) but couldn't figure out a solution on my own.

Here is one more `data.frame` in order to provide a reproducible example

```
Apple = structure(list(Name = c("ABIDING", "ABLE", "ABROAD", "ACROSS", 
"ACT", "ADVANTAGE"), freq = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L)), .Names = c("Name", 
"freq"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'm trying to figure out how to obtain `output`from `Apple`, `Berry`, and `Orange`. I am looking for a solution that would work for multiple dataframes preferably without me having to provide the dataframes manually.

You can assume that the data.frame names to be processed for getting the `output` is available in a list `df_names`:

```
 df_names = c("Apple","Berry","Orange")
```

Or, you can also assume that every `data.frame` in the `Global Environment` needs to be processed to create `output`.

Comment: Can you create a list of the data frames and use lapply?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have all your data frames in an environment, you can get them into a named list then use package *reshape2* to reshape the list.  If desired, you can then set the first column as the row names.

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(melt(Filter(is.data.frame, mget(ls()))), L1 ~ Name)
#       L1 ABIDING ABLE ABROAD ACHIEVE ACROSS ACT ACTION ACTIVISM ACTS ADDICTION ADVANCE ADVANCING ADVANTAGE
# 1  Apple       1    1      1      NA      4   2     NA       NA   NA        NA      NA        NA         1
# 2  Berry      NA   NA     NA      NA     NA   2      2        1    1         1       1        NA        NA
# 3 Orange      NA   NA     NA       1      3   1      1       NA   NA        NA       1         1        NA
```

Note:  This assumes all your data is in the global environment and that no other data frames are present except the ones to be used here.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
list(Apple = Apple, Orange = Orange, Berry = Berry)  %>%
          bind_rows(.id = "objName") %>% 
          spread(Name, freq, fill = 0) 
#    objName ABIDING ABLE ABROAD ACHIEVE ACROSS ACT ACTION ACTIVISM ACTS ADDICTION ADVANCE ADVANCING ADVANTAGE
#1   Apple       1    1      1       0      4   2      0        0    0         0       0         0         1
#2   Berry       0    0      0       0      0   2      2        1    1         1       1         0         0
#3  Orange       0    0      0       1      3   1      1        0    0         0       1         1         0
```

---

As you have 72 data.frames, it is better not to create all these objects in the global environment.  Instead, read the dataset files in a `list` and then do the processing.  Suppose, if the files are all in the working directory

```
files <- list.files(pattern = ".csv")
lapply(files, read.csv, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

and then do the processing with `bind_rows` as above.   As it is not clear about the file names, we cannot comment on how to create the 'objName'